# JavaScript - compare 2 arrays with split with space

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
sentence []
keywords []
```

for example `sentence []` :

```
sentence [0] = "my car is blue"
sentence [1] = "the dog is sleeping"
sentence [2] = "I am in the kitchen"
sentence [3] = "How are you"
```

and `keywords []` :

```
keywords [0] = "my"
keywords [1] = " "
keywords [2] = "car"
keywords [3] = " "
keywords [4] = "is"
keywords [5] = " "
keywords [6] = "blue"
keywords [7] = "gghcxfkjc"
keywords [8] = "532jj"
keywords [9] = "How"
keywords [10] = " "
keywords [11] = "are"
keywords [12] = " "
keywords [13] = "you"
keywords [14] = " "
keywords [15] = "tech"
```

So for instance, I need to detect that  "*my car is blue*" and "*How are you*" are in the `keywords` array.
Notice that keywords [] follows the order of the sentence.

How I can proceed to compare and detect this kind on info?

**[EDIT] I need to know the index of each words matched in keywords[]**
For instance 0,1,2,3,4 for the first sentence and 9,10,11,12,13 for the other sentence.

Comment: Just to clarify, every word in the sentence must match a keyword to pass a truth test?

Comment: Probably by iterating over the arrays, while having a flag for true or false

Comment: `keywords.join('').indexOf('sentence-to-check') !== -1` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just `join` the keywords and look up the sentence in the resulting string:

```
kw = keywords.join("")
sentence.forEach(function(s) {
    console.log(s, kw.indexOf(s) >= 0);
});
```

prints

```
my car is blue true
the dog is sleeping false
I am in the kitchen false
How are you true
```

Comment: So much cleaner than my mess :P I'd include a IE9+ disclaimer, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm too lazy to write that everytime )) Feel free to edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to loop through `sentence`, ans check if any of the sentences are in the keywords.

This'll do the trick:

```
// Build a big string of all keywords
var keyWordLine = keywords.join('').toLowerCase(); // "my car is bluegghcxfkjc532jjHow are you tech"
// Loop through all sentences
for(var i = 0; i < sentence; i++){
    // Check the current sentence
    if(keyWordLine.indexOf(sentence[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1){
        // sentence is in the keywords!
    }else{
        // sentence is not in the keywords!
    }
}
```

Now, what you'll do with these results is up to you. You could, for example, build an array that includes only the sentences that appear in `keywords`:

```js
var keywords = ["my", " ", "car", " ", "is", " ", "blue", "gghcxfkjc", "532jj", "How", " ", "are", " ", "you", " ", "tech"],
    sentence = ["my car is blue", "the dog is sleeping", "I am in the kitchen", "How are you"],
    keyWordLine = keywords.join('').toLowerCase(),
    output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sentence; i++){
    if(keyWordLine.indexOf(sentence[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1){
         output.push(sentence[i]);
    }
}
alert(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I will need to know the index of each words that match in keywords[]. For instance O,1,2,3,4 for the first sentence and 9,10,11,12,13 for the other sentence.